# How large can the dimension of a 'Span of powers of a finite field basis' be?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, inequalities, finite-fields, computational-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. For finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ and $d\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, I am considering the following quantity, where we interpret the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ also as a $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space.

$$M_{p^k}^{(d)}:=\max_{\{\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_k\}\text{ is a basis of } \mathbb{F}_{p^k}}\Big\{\dim\langle\beta_1^d, \cdots, \beta_k^d \rangle\Big\}$$

For fixed $p^k$ and $d$, is there any known results on exact value or bounds of this quantity? I am both interested in the general case and the special case of $d=2$. Any idea or comment will be very helpful. The following are some very basic facts that I have observed, but I could not go further.

- When $d$ is a power of $p$, it holds that $M_{p^k}^{(d)}=k$, regarding a normal basis and Frobenius map.
- $M_{p^k}^{(d)}\ge \lfloor \frac{k-1}{d} \rfloor + 1$, regarding first $(\lfloor \frac{k-1}{d} \rfloor + 1)$ elements of a primitive element basis of the form $\{1, \beta, \beta^2, \cdots, \beta^{k-1}\}$.
- If $\gcd (d,p^k-1)=1$, then $M_{p^k}^{(d)}=k$, regarding a primitive element basis of the form $\{1, \beta, \beta^2, \cdots, \beta^{k-1}\}$. Indeed, $\beta^d$ is a primitive element, and $\{1, \beta^d, \beta^{2d}, \cdots, \beta^{(k-1)d}\}$ is again a basis. (from the discussion with Donggeon Yhee)

---

Some experimental results:

A primitive element basis of the form $\{1, \beta, \beta^2, \cdots, \beta^{k-1}\}$ usually gives the optimal basis.

$p=2$ case:

- $M_{2^k}^{(3)}=k$ for $k\le 100$, except $M_{2^2}^{(3)}=1$
- $M_{2^k}^{(5)}=k$ for $k\le 100$, except $M_{2^4}^{(5)}=2$
- $M_{2^k}^{(6)}=k$ for $k\le 100$, except $M_{2^2}^{(6)}=1$
- $M_{2^k}^{(7)}=k$ for $k\le 100$, except $M_{2^3}^{(7)}=1$
- $M_{2^k}^{(9)}=k$ for $k\le 100$, except $M_{2^2}^{(9)}=1$ and $M_{2^6}^{(9)}\ge 3$
- $M_{2^k}^{(10)}=k$ for $k\le 100$, except $M_{2^4}^{(10)}=2$
- $M_{2^k}^{(25)}=k$ for $k\le 100$, except $M_{2^4}^{(25)}=2$
- $M_{2^k}^{(27)}=k$ for $k\le 100$, except $M_{2^2}^{(27)}=1$ and $M_{2^6}^{(27)}\ge 3$

$p=3$ case:

- $M_{3^k}^{(2)}=k$ for $k\le 100$
- $M_{3^k}^{(4)}=k$ for $k\le 100$, except $M_{3^2}^{(4)} = 1$
- $M_{3^k}^{(5)}=k$ for $k\le 100$
- $M_{3^k}^{(6)}=k$ for $k\le 100$

$p=5$ case:

- $M_{5^k}^{(2)}=k$ for $k\le 100$
- $M_{5^k}^{(3)}=k$ for $k\le 100$
- $M_{5^k}^{(4)}=k$ for $k\le 100$
- $M_{5^k}^{(6)}=k$ for $k\le 100$, except $M_{5^2}^{(6)} = 1$

Comment: $p\ne 2$?  ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @MarkSapir: For the special case of d=2, I am interested in the p>2 case, since the p=2 case is trivial by the first bullet-item. For the general case of d>3, I am more interested in the p=2 case. Thank you for your attention:)

Comment: ok. So we can assume that $d>3$, $d\ne 4=2^2$  and $p=2$. What is it for $\mathbb{F}_{32}$?

Comment: Oops, my bad...  I meant $d \ge 3$

Comment: Then what is it for $\mathbb{F}_8$. Is it $3$. and, in general, $k$ for every odd $k$?

Comment: @MarkSapir: $M^{(d)}_8 = 3$ holds for $d=3,5,6$. However, $M^{(7)}_8 = 1$. I will add some experimental results to the question soon.

Comment: It seems that $M_{p^k}^{\left(m\frac{p^k-1}{p-1}\right)}=1$ for all $p$, $k$ and $m$

Comment: I updated the experimental results for p=3,5. Sorry, my code contained an error.

Comment: More generally, $M_{p^{ij}}^{\left(m\frac{p^{ij}-1}{p^j-1}\right)}=j$

Comment: (...which is more or less obvious: $\beta^{\frac{p^{ij}-1}{p^j-1}}\in\mathbb F_{p^j}$ for any $\beta\in\mathbb F_{p^{ij}}$)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: In your last comment, what does $i$ denote? If I am free to choose $i=1$, then it contradicts the experiments with $M_{p^k}^{(d)}\neq k$.

Comment: You are right, I should be more careful. I only could write "$\leqslant j$", not "$=j$". Presumably there are also examples of "$<j$" for $i>1$...

Comment: What might be true is that if $\beta_1$, ..., $\beta_{ij}$ is a basis of $\mathbb F_{p^{ij}}$ then $\beta_1^d$, ..., $\beta_{ij}^d$ span $\mathbb F_{p^j}$ for $d=\frac{p^{ij}-1}{p^j-1}$

Comment: I proved $M_{p^k}^{(d)} \ge \text{ord}_t(p)$, where $t=\frac{p^k-1}{\gcd(p^k-1,d)}$. I am already very satisfied with this fact. I will add an answer to the post after weekends. Thank you all for discussions:)

Comment: Are you still planning to add [that answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400701/how-large-can-the-dimension-of-a-span-of-powers-of-a-finite-field-basis-be#comment1024014_400701)?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field and $\mathbb{E}$ be an extension of a prime degree (say $q$). Let $d$ be co-prime to $|\mathbb{F}|^q-1$.

$\langle\beta_1^d,...,\beta_q^d\rangle$ is a $\mathbb{F}$-subspace of $\mathbb{E}$, whose dimension over $\mathbb{F}$ is $q$. In other words, $\{\beta_1^d,...,\beta_q^d\}$ is again a basis of $\mathbb{E}$ over $\mathbb{F}$.

Recall your question.

At first, assume $gcd(d, p^k-1)=1$. Let $k=q_1q_2...q_m$ be a prime factorization and $k_j:=q_1q_2...q_j$.

A basis of $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ can be given as $\mathcal{B}_m\times \mathcal{B}_{m-1}\times ...\times \mathcal{B}_1$ where $\mathcal{B}_j$ is a basis of $\mathbb{F}_{p^{k_j}}$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^{k_{j-1}}}$. Thus, $M_{p^k}^{(d)}=k$ in the case.

Secondly, we consider $gcd(d,p^k-1)=n\neq 1$. Then $\{\beta_1^d,...,\beta_k^d\}$ lies in a proper subspace of $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}=\{0, x~|~x^{p^k-1}=1 \pmod{p}\}$. Then we reduce your question to $d'|d$ and $k'|k$ and $gcd(d',p^{k'}-1)=1$. Here $d'=\frac{d}{n}$ and $k'$ be the maximum divisor of $k$ so that $n|\frac{p^k-1}{p^{k'}-1}$. ("maximum" or "maximal" seems to be more proper than "largest"...)

typo : Sorry for the first assumption on $d$. $q-1$ is replaced by $|\mathbb{F}|^q-1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer:) Your inspection on $\gcd(d,p^k-1)$ seems to be correct, comparing with the experimental results. However, I could not follow your answer. Can you kindly elaborate more on the following? (i) Why is the dimension of $\langle \beta_1^d, \cdots, \beta_q^d \rangle$ equals to $q$? (ii) How can we deduce that $M_{p^k}^{(d)}$ from construction of a basis?

Comment: (i) Under the assumption gcd$(d,...)$, $\beta_1^d\neq \beta_2^d$ so that the subspace has dimension at least 2. It should be then $q$.
(ii) In the first case, (if I'm correct) $d$-power preserves basis property, at each $B_j$'s. Consequently, a basis of $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ is replaced by another basis by the $d$-power operation : the product of new $\mathcal{B}$'s gives a  new basis of $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$. Thus $M_{p^k}^{(d)}=k$.

Comment: Sorry (i) has big error. dim=q is not justified yet, my mistake.

Comment: Although your proof may be wrong, I find your statement "$\gcd (d,p^k-1)=1 \implies M_{p^k}^{(d)}=k$" very compelling. Thanks for the insight. I will add it to the question as a conjecture.

Comment: I proved the statement. I cannot understand how I couldn't see this before. Please check the edited question.